# Difference between --default and --store_const in argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I read the following in the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) documentation:

> '`store_const`' - This stores the value specified by the const keyword
>   argument. (Note that the const keyword argument defaults to the rather
>   unhelpful None.) The '`store_const`' action is most commonly used with
>   optional arguments that specify some sort of flag. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_const', const=42)
> >>> parser.parse_args('--foo'.split()) Namespace(foo=42)`
> ```

How is this different from setting a default value for the argument with the [`default`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#default) option?

Answer (score 40):

Below describes the difference between `default` and `store_const`. Because of poor naming, this can indeed be very confusing.

There are basically two types of arguments Python supports:

**Argument with value**

Example: `--seed 42`

You cannot omit the value part even if you set default as shown below:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--seed', default=42)

parser.parse_args('--seed 20'.split()) # seed is now 20
parser.parse_args(''.split()) # seed is now 42

parser.parse_args('--seed'.split()) # ERROR, must supply argument value
```

**Argument without value**

Example: `--no-cuda`

Here you cannot supply value to the argument, either argument exist or it doesn't. The `action = "store_const"` means that the argument value is whatever is set in the `const` parameter when the argument is present. If argument is not present then it takes the value specified in the `default` parameter.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--use-cuda', action='store_const', const=False, default=True)

parser.parse_args('--use-cuda'.split()) # use-cuda is now False
parser.parse_args(''.split()) # use-cuda is now True

parser.parse_args('--use-cuda True'.split()) # ERROR: unrecognized arguments: True
```

**Using `const` without `default`**

Now what if you did not specify `default`? Well, in that case, `default` just assumes the value of `None` as shown below:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--use-cuda', action='store_const', const=False)

parser.parse_args('--use-cuda'.split()) # use-cuda is now False
parser.parse_args(''.split()) # use-cuda is now None

parser.parse_args('--use-cuda True'.split()) # ERROR: unrecognized arguments: True
```

**Shortcut for boolean arguments**

Now you can see that the value of `const` and `default` are usually opposite for the boolean arguments. To make this convenient, Python has shortcut actions called `store_true` and `store_false`. The `store_true` is same as `const=True` and `default=False`. The `store_false` other way around.

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful thanks.

Comment: Excellent and concise explanation of `const` and `default` for argparse. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

What did you get with `parse_args(''.split())`?  I'd expect `foo=None`.

Now add a `default='39'` to your argument definition.

`default` is the value that the attribute gets when the argument is absent.  `const` is the value it gets when given.  Note also that `const` is allowed only when the action is `store_const` (and a few other special cases).

Note what happens when I define a `store_true` action:

```
In [30]: p.add_argument('--bar', action='store_true')
Out[30]: _StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=0, 
    const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

The `Action` object that it creates has a `const=True` attribute, and `default=False` attribute.  It also has `nargs=0`.  It is a `store_const` action with these special values.

[An 'advanced' user could experiment with `add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default='one', const='two')`].

Comment: `add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default='one', const='two')` is amazing